# parsing a string then storing in array to recall into a variable arduino

Tags: arrays, parsing, serial-port, arduino

i am sending the following data to the arduino over serial:

```
c1:255c2:0c3:0c4:255c5:0
```

i need to separate this into 5 variables, so it will eventually become

```
val1=255
val2=0
val3=0
val4=255
val5=0
```

so my first step would be to separate the incoming serial data into

```
c1:255
c2:0
c3:0
c4:255
c5:0
```

then to parse the data so that it drops the correct integer into the correct variable so the int in c1 becomes val1 etc.

This will eventually let me set a value and so i need to be able to recall the value easily.

i understand i need to use an array but i have spent hours looking at how to do this and got nowhere, can someone show me how to do each of these steps, i am a NOOB so be kind! thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not to give it all way, in basket, the following links of my projects have similar features that you are looking for. From there code you will find the pieces of the puzzles of how to build the array and dissect it looking for the desired components you are looking for:

http://mpflaga.github.io/Sparkfun-MP3-Player-Shield-Arduino-Library/_file_player_8ino_source.html#l00132

https://gist.github.com/mpflaga/5350562#file-trackplayer-ino-L131

https://gist.github.com/mpflaga/5351285#file-filenameplayer-ino-L123

Not to say there are better ways.